# Multiline Word Wrapping having points

Tags: java, word-wrap

We've to do word wrap in java. For eg. considering the lines (exactly the way they're written):

```
When the ship, mostly carrying people from north Andhra Pradesh and south Odisha, 
for labour work in the Andaman and Nicobar islands, 
A.  sailed from the Visakhapatnam harbour, none had any suspicion of the harrowing.
B.  The ship was stuck for several hours in the high seas about 14 nautical miles

Only on the intervention of senior officials and the Navy, the ship crew was advised to 
return to the port for undertaking repairs on one of 
the defunct generators noticed mid-sea.
```

Rules we've to follow:

1. Lines should be of 98 characters
2. If point is coming like A. and B. then they've to come in different lines
   whether they're of 98 characters or not.

We've tried following the rules and written the code but unable to handle the end of line. Because the user at front-end is not typing the text. He is copying the text from wordpad and pasting it in the same way it is written above.

Due to this unable to get \n or \r which ideally has to come if user press enter in the end of lines.

After wrapping the text, result should come in this way:

```
When the ship, mostly carrying people from north Andhra Pradesh and south Odisha, for labour work
in the Andaman and Nicobar islands, 
A.  sailed from the Visakhapatnam harbour, none had any suspicion of the harrowing.
B.  The ship was stuck for several hours in the high seas about 14 nautical miles

Only on the intervention of senior officials and the Navy, the ship crew was advised to return to
the port for undertaking repairs on one of the defunct generators noticed mid-sea.
```

Can anyone help us on the same.

Comment: What do you have so far? Show us your code.

Comment: The code is written on my company's machine. If I copy the same. It will get traced. The code I've written is made an ArrayList and saved all 98 characters lines into different indexes of list. In the end getting a single complete paragraph having all the lines.

Comment: Without seeing your code it will be very difficult to give any real help. The only comments I can give is to first split the text in sentences. Then print it out one char at a time. When you hit 98 chars, line break. And if the sentence is one char long, assume it's a bullet so insert line break before it.

Comment: how to split text in sentences. how would compiler know that now one sentence is over and we've to start with another one. Because in the end of one sentence we don't have anything like \n or \r or delimiter. It is copied from word into an application. Then application send the data to the code in the same format I've written above.

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve] of what you are having difficulties with

Answer (score 1):

I will not give you the full answer, because this sounds very much like homework. And SO will not do your homework for you. But we do help out!

So, basically, you have a large blob of text that you want to split up. A sentence is terminated by a dot (`.`) (among others, adapt as needed).
If, in your case, a sentence is two chars long, and one is a dot (eg `A.`) then you assume it's a bullet/point.

To get the text-blob into sentences, simply split on the dot.
`final String[] sentences = text.split("\\.");`

Now you can work on each sentence. Since your bullets come after a comma, you also need to split on commas to get each part of a sentence and check if that part is a bullet.

Here is something to get you started.

```
private void splitText(){
    final String text = "When the ship, mostly carrying people from north Andhra Pradesh and south Odisha,    for labour work in the Andaman and Nicobar islands,    A.  sailed from the Visakhapatnam harbour, none had any suspicion of the harrowing.   B.  The ship was stuck for several hours in the high seas about 14 nautical miles    Only on the intervention of senior officials and the Navy, the ship crew was advised to    return to the port for undertaking repairs on one of    the defunct generators noticed mid-sea.";
    int maxLength = 98;
    final String pText = text.replaceAll("\\s", " ");
    final String[] sentences = pText.split("\\.");

    for(String sentence : sentences){
        String[] parts = sentence.split("\\,");
        int lineLength = 0;
        for(int p=0, partLength=parts.length; p<partLength; ++p){
            String part = parts[p];
            int length = part.length();
            int trimmedLength = part.trim().length();
            if(trimmedLength == 1){
                System.out.println();
            }
            for(int i=0; i<length; ++i){
                char c = part.charAt(i);
                System.out.print(c);
                ++lineLength;
                if(lineLength == maxLength){
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            if(p != partLength-1){ System.out.print(",");}
        }
    }
    System.out.print(".");
}
```

With this, you get the following output

```
When the ship, mostly carrying people from north Andhra Pradesh and south Odisha,    for labour work
 in the Andaman and Nicobar islands
    A  sailed from the Visakhapatnam harbour, none had any suspicion of the harrowing
   B  The ship was stuck for several hours in the high seas about 14 nautical miles    Only on the int
ervention of senior officials and the Navy, the ship crew was advised to    return to the port for undertaking repairs on one of    the defunct generators noticed mid-sea.
```

This is *deliberately* a non-finished solution, since it very much sounds like homework. It should however push you in the right direction to get something working.

Comment: Sir, Thank you very much for helping me out.. I know it sounds like homework. But I've tried a lot but unable to complete the code perfectly. User from front end is not at all passing data in appropriate or fix format.. Only one thing I've to ask, how can I push the last paragraph after 2nd point . Right now the word "Only" startss from the end 2nd point. Could you please help me last time. I would be really thankful to you.

Comment: @Tanul You could look for multiple spaces and assume thats means the end of a point, or you could assume that an uppercase means a new sentence. Or combine them. Mulitiple spaces followed by an uppercase char means that the point has ended, so insert newline.

Comment: I've tried understanding the code but there is one thing would not understand. How it is writing the second point. Means how it break after completing first point and shift it to next para. Because the same I've to think for last paragraph. Trying, but unable to understood exactly.

Comment: @Tanul Point `A` ends with a period. So when it reaches `B`, it sees that it's a one-letter-sentence, and inserts a newline before it.

Comment: I've tried a lot by adding a full-stop in the end of 2nd point. Still unable to shift last para to next line. Could you please do some changes inside the code for shifting the last para to another line, means, the line, after the end of second point.

Comment: @Tanul The easiest approach you can take is to split yet another time, but this time on double spaces (eg. `part.split("  ")`). This will split your parts when there are two spaces anywhere. This is the *easiest* approach, not the best. But it should push you into a working solution.